# ASP.NET default database not populating, code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

At one point my identity tables were populating, but then I realized I had two separate DB's being created, one based on the identity models (ASP.NET default) and the other on my custom models.  So I then merged the two into one database, and that is when my identity tables stopped populating.

When I run the app and register users, it is supposed to populate the database with new users.  So my tables are created, but the data (users, roles, etc.) are not populating.

Here is my context class:

```
    public class FlavorPingContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public FlavorPingContext() : base("name=FlavorPingContext")
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MerchantDetails> MerchantDetails { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Follower> Followers { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.FollowerMenuItemMerchant> FollowerMenuItemMerchants { get; set; }

    public DbSet<IdentityUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityRole> Role { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }


     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
    // Primary keys
    builder.Entity<Follower>().HasKey(q => q.FollowerID);
    builder.Entity<MenuItem>().HasKey(q => q.MenuItemID);
    builder.Entity<Merchant>().HasKey(q => q.MerchantID);
    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>().HasKey(q => 
        new { 
            q.FollowerID, q.MenuItemID, q.MerchantID
        });

    // Relationships
    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Follower)
        .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.FollowerID);

    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.MenuItem)
        .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.MenuItemID);

    builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Merchant)
    .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.MerchantID);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

    //removes plural naming in DB tables
    builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    builder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    //This is suppposed to populate Identity tables.
    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.PasswordHash).HasMaxLength(500);
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.SecurityStamp).HasMaxLength(500);
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(50);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Role");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().Property(u => u.ClaimType).HasMaxLength(150);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().Property(u => u.ClaimValue).HasMaxLength(500);
}


}
```

Here is my create Merchant method:

```
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MerchantID,MerchantName,email,website")] Merchant merchant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid){

            merchant.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Merchants.Add(merchant);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(merchant);
    }
```

Here is my Register

```
     [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                //Assign Role to user Here 
                await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.role);
                //Ends Here
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: when you say "populating" what do you mean? Populating with what? And when?

Comment: When I run the app and register users, it is supposed to populate the database with new users.
I will add that explanation above.

Comment: can you show the code that is saving the users? just the relevant bits...

Comment: I just added everything above.  I should have thought about reviewing that more, definitely think that is where the error is happening.

Comment: when debugging, what's the result of `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync` - is `result.Succeeded` true? if not, it will have a list of errors in there

Comment: Warning 1 'FlavorPing.Models.FlavorPingContext.Users' hides inherited member 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole,string,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim>.Users'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

Comment: It is succeeding, as the code in the If statement is still being run.  But the above warning is being shown.